# ruby add strings from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a simple breadcrumb in ruby but I am not sure how to really implement my logic.

Let's say I have an array of words that are taken from my `request.path.split("/)` `["", "products", "women", "dresses"]`
I want to push the strings into another array so then in the end I have `["/", "/products", "products/women", "products/women/dresses"]` and I will use it as my breadcrumb solution.

I am not good at ruby but for now I came up with following

```
cur_path = request.path.split('/')

cur_path.each do |link|
  arr = []
  final_link = '/'+ link
  if cur_path.find_index(link) > 1
    # add all the previous array items with the exception of the index 0
  else
    arr.push(final_link)
  end
end
```

The results should be `["/", "/products", "/products/women", "/products/women/dresses"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby's `Pathname` has some string-based path manipulation utilities, e.g. [`ascend`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#ascend-method):

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new('/products/women/dresses').ascend.map(&:to_s).reverse
#=> ["/", "/products", "/products/women", "/products/women/dresses"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my simplest solution:

```rb
a = '/products/women/dresses'.split('/')
a.each_with_index.map { |e,i| e.empty? ? '/' : a[0..i].join('/')  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another option using [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
ary = '/products/women/dresses'.split('/')
ary[1..].map
        .with_index
        .with_object([]) { |(folder, idx), path| path << [path[idx-1], folder].join('/') }.unshift('/')
```

---

Or also:

```
(ary.size - 1).times.map { |i| ary.first(i + 2).join('/') }.unshift('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` and [`with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index) it can be done like this:

```
arr = ["", "products", "women", "dresses"]
arr.map.with_index { |item, index| "#{arr[0...index].join('/')}/#{item}" }
```